# Retrieve a single object instead of a list/array

Tags: node.js, xml, dom, xpath

I am using this xml file that I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85)

I am trying to retrieve the value of the author. So with this code:

```
var val = xpath.select('/catalog/book[1]/author', root);
```

I was hoping it will return: `Gambardella, Matthew`. But instead it writes an array with NodeName, tagName, docType, length, firsChild etc.
If I then do:

```
val.forEach(function(n) {
    console.log("Each n: "+n);  
  });
```

I get: `Each n: <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>`

So my question is, how do I get just the attribute value? I also tried to do `val.getAttribue()`

Here is the entire code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var xmlDom = require('xmldom');
var xpath = require('xpath');

fs.readFile('books.xml', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  } 
  
  var parser = new xmlDom.DOMParser(); 
  var serializer = new xmlDom.XMLSerializer();

  var root = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml'); 
  var val = xpath.select('/catalog/book[1]/author', root);
  
  val.forEach(function(n) {
    console.log("Each n: "+n);  
  });  
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
var val = xpath.select('/catalog/book[1]/author', root);
```

to

```
var val = xpath.select('/catalog/book[1]/author/text(), root);
```

At that point:

```
val.forEach(function(n) {
    console.log("Each n: "+n);  
  });
```

should output:

```
Each n: Gambardella, Matthew
```